# php: echo an error message

Tags: php

code :

```
$searchText = '3423,  2453,  3245  ,  2425,  6765';     

$numbers = str_replace(", ", ",", $searchText);

    $code = explode(",", $numbers);

   if ( (preg_match("/[^0-9]/i"), $code) || (strlen($code) != 4) ) {

            $searchingError= 'Can not cantain string and more than 4 digists number!';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo "alert('" . $searchingError . "')";
            echo "</script>";   
    }   

    function validate ($a) {
    if (ctype_digit($a) && (strlen($a) == 4)) { 
        return "'$a'" ;
    } else {
        //$searchingError= 'Can not cantain string and more than 4 digists number!';
        //echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        //echo "alert('" . $searchingError . "')";
        //echo "</script>";         
    }
}

$parsed = array_map( "validate",$code);

print_r($parsed);

$code = '(' . preg_replace('/\,+/', ',',implode(',', $parsed)) . ')';

echo '<br />' . $code;
```

In this code, is there a way to identify $searchText have only 4 digits numbers or it contain string etc. If it's so, I want to echo an error message.

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: be VERY careful with how you're building your JS error popups. One extra `'` somewhere and you've killed that JS code block. As well, consider how utterly stupidly annoying your site will be if someone makes multiple errors. Personally, any site that yells multiple JS alerts at me when it could simply do one single combined error message is a site that I will never ever use again.

Answer (score 2):

Check if $code is a text using `is_int` and the length of each number using `strlen();`
in an if statement:

```
if (is_int($code)) {
    if (strlen($num1) = 4 && strlen($num2) ...) {
        //code here 
    }
    else
        echo "Error.";
}
else 
    echo "The search is text";
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work to verify that they are digits only and 4 characters only...

```
       //is not digits                or    //is not 4 characters in length
 if ( (preg_match("/[^0-9]/i"), $code) || (strlen($code) != 4) ) {alert error...}
```

Comment: there is a parse error in this line... I updated code with your code.

Answer (score 0):

**GOT IT!**

```
 <?php

 $a = "4444 , 111X , 565656, 4444";

 $a = str_replace(" ", "", $a);

 $b = explode(",",$a);

 function validate($v){

if ((strlen($v)!=4)||(preg_match("/[^0-9]/i", $v))) { echo 'error<br/>'; }else{ echo 'success<br/>'; };

 }

 array_filter($b,"validate");


 echo 'complete';


 ?>
```